# Cleanup of AudioNodes in Web Audio

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

The [Web Audio API docs](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) don't really explain what do with an `AudioNode` once you're done with it. For example, if I am done with an `AudioBufferSourceNode` and I want to get rid of it, is it enough to just call `noteOff()` or do I need to `disconnect` it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's enough to just call `noteOff()`, or if the `AudioBufferSourceNode` is not looping it will just finish by itself when it reaches the end of sample data (without needing to call `noteOff()`).  It is not necessary to disconnect it.

Comment: I found your original proposal thread in the w3c mailing list archives. That helped me understand quite a bit actually. Link for those interested: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-audio/2010Jun/0010.html

Comment: It's worth noting that the spec changed and `noteOff` is now `stop`.